# Float or integer for storing coordinates

Tags: c++, winapi, image-processing, mfc

I am working on an application which is basically related with drawing annotation on image using MFC's api. 
The coordinates required for drawing these annotation is persisted in xml file.
It also handle the scaling of annotations on changing the zoom-level of image.

The problem is that when scaling the coordinates the immediate result is double or float, but we save the result as integer, which result in lots of errors/deviations.

Will it be nice to save the coordinate as float in the xml, also performing the immediate operation on float?

And finally convert it to integer for using in api like LineTo(), MoveTo() which needs long.

Any suggestion or advice on this will be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to save the value as a floating point value, go ahead and do so.

Comment: Can you give some opinion?

Comment: Well, if you want to be subject to rounding errors and inaccuracies, then round all your coordinates to integers. If you want to minimise those problems, use floating point values.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Will there be rounding errors if fixed-point is used?  For example, using integers to represent 1.0E-3 or 1.0E-6 values?  My understanding is that to avoid floating point inaccuracies, use fixed point.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews There will always be rounding errors. Fixed point doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've worked with graphics pipelines for quite some time.

For something that involves scaling, I insist that you store all your data as doubles.  Especially when you plan to go from integer to floating-point and floating-point to integer.  Far less error when scaling as well.

There is no harm in storing these values in XML any differently than integers.

Also, CPUs these days are quite optimized for floating-point operations.

Comment: Do graphic processors work better with floating point or fixed point?  For example, should I use <1, 1.5> or <10, 15> as a coordinate?

Comment: Generally it doesn't matter these days.  Integer is faster on CPU.  Float is faster on GPU.  But this is extreme generalization.

Answer (score 0):

When serializing the coordinates into the xml, you can use `reinterpret_cast<int>` to simply save them as an integer with the same binary representation as the float. Conversely, during deserialization, use `reinterpret_cast<float>` to recover the original number. You shouldn't lose precision on saving/loading this way.

As far as errors go, the solution is trivial: don't save as integer. Keep the floats (I'd even get behind PhoenixX_2's suggestion to upgrade to doubles), then, while drawing, cast them to a temporary int variable.

edit: Note that if you do decide to use double instead of float, you'll need to account for that during serialization, as doubles are 64-bit, not 32. You could also just save the number as a human-readable decimal, which is probably the most obvious way to do it.

Comment: This won't work, because double take 64 bits and int take only 32 bits. You'd save the lower 32 bits of the binaray representation of the double value.

Comment: If you are using _float_ instead of _double_, it should work, but it's more reasonable to use _double_ because you get more precision and less rounding problems.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to mention about the 64 bit issue. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Doesn't even work for floats: write from a low-endian machine, read into a big-endian one, ka-boom! Never use implicit data transformations in a data interchange format like xml.

Comment: Thanks all for your great suggestions and discussion.